# Two AngularJS $timeout timers clashing?

Tags: angularjs, twilio

I am using Twilio to set up a phone conversation. The mobile app asks a websocket for information such as the time when the conversation started. The asking is done every second using a $timeout. When the call connects, the first timer stops. A second one begins to count the duration of the call. When the call disconnects, the duration timer stops and the timer to ask the websocket for information starts again. Here lies the problem. When calling the $timeout to ask the websocket, the duration also continues. It looks like the two  are clashing. I am new to AngularJS, my knowledge on $apply and $timeout etc is limited.

The $timeout for the duration is located in a controller. The other is located in a service.

I have tried to put the $timeout.cancel() functions in a $apply but this doesn't seem to work.

$timeout in controller:

```
 var updateCounter = function() {
        $scope.time++;
        timer = $timeout(updateCounter, 1000);
}

    Twilio.Device.disconnect(function(conn) {

        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            $timeout.cancel(timer);
            LimServ.askTimeStamp($scope.username); //above $timeout cancel works when this line is removed.
          });
        })
    }
```

$timeout in service:

```
  var getLimitTimestamp = function() {
    WebFac.send(userName);
    timerLim = $timeout(getLimitTimestamp, 1000);
  }

  this.askTimeStamp = function(username) {
    userName = username;
    getLimitTimestamp();
  }
```

timerLim is canceled using `$timeout.cancel(timerLim);`

If more information is needed, please let me know!

Comment: So what makes you say  $timeout.cancel(timer); doesn't work when you add the LimServ.askTimeStamp($scope.username); line?

Comment: Yes, when I remove LimServ.askTimeStamp($scope.username), $timeout.cancel(timer) works. When the line is not removed, the 'timer' keeps on going.

Comment: At what point in the code is the updateCounter() function called, and may the WebFac.send(userName); instruction in any way have anything to do with this function being called? it may be helpfull if you could provide a bit more code - possibly the complete controller & service, maybe also the view I'm guessing the time variable is bound to

Comment: Thank you for your time! I have just found out the issue was in my code. When using the websocket, I get a variety of possible events. One of them is answered (when a timestamp 'answered' has been written into the database on the server). The other one is 'completed' when the call has ended and a 'completed' timestamp has been written into the db. The problem was that the answered event was called when the websocket was restarted, because the 'completed' timestamp had not been written into the database yet, which caused the 'answered' event to fire and restart the duration timer.

Comment: nice :) good work